# Compare an array value to an int value within an if statement

Tags: c++, ide, operands

I've been having trouble writing a conditional if statement that compares one entry of an array, to an initger value

```
void test_part3(triangleWcolor ArrayIn[], triangleWcolor ArrayOut[], triangleWcolor perimiter[], triangleWcolor max_val[], int arraysize)
{   
    for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
    {
        triangleWcolor perimiter[arraysize];
        ArrayIn[i].inputRandomValues();
        cout << "Input Array" << endl;
        ArrayIn[i].printInfo();
        ArrayIn[i].getPerimiter();
        perimiter[i]=ArrayIn[i].getPerimiter();
    }

    for(int i=0; i< arraysize; i++)
    {
        if(perimiter[i]<75 && perimiter[i]>25]
        {
            cout << "Output Array Values" << endl;
            ArrayOut[i] = ArrayIn[i];
            ArrayOut[i].printInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

The printInfo(); inputRnadomValues(); and getPerimiter(); functions are ll located withing a structure "triangleWcolor" in a header file. I've verified these are giving me the desired outputs through debugging. When I try to run this segment of code I get the message: [Error] no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'triangleWcolor' and 'int')

With that out of the way I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to how I should proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: This code does not compile on my machine.  Lots of pieces are missing.  My guess is triangleWcolor does not have an `operator<` for int.

Comment: Show `triangleWcolor`. does it have `operator <(int) const` defined ? Should `perimiter[i]<75` be something like `perimiter[i].get_vale() < 75` ?

Comment: You can't pass perimiter as an argument and declare it locally.

Comment: You should clean up your question after visiting the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Also, you should post a [Minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise the answers already posted are somewhat guessing at the answer. Here's a question: Why would something called "perimiter" return a color? Maybe there is something a bit more basic that's at fault here. Should a perimeter return a color? Is that perhaps why there is an error, because a color is not a distance?

Comment: I must admit I'm drawing somewhat of a conclusion here, but naming things is very important, and the compiler error is basically saying "Hey, a color isn't a number!"

Comment: (And it's right)

Answer (score 0):

the error is clear you are comparing an object triangleWcolor to a int:

```
 'operator<' (operand types are 'triangleWcolor' and 'int')
```

If triangleWcolor is an enum, you could maybe try a static_cast on it, but you should be sure this is still meaningful (enum values are contiguous)

Comment: "enum values are contiguous" - not necessarily. `enum class Foo { Bar = 42, Baz = 100 };`

Comment: I agree, that's why I say he must check this is meaningful before casting

Comment: Why do you think an enumeration is being used at all? The OP didn't even mention them.

Comment: Try to read every word of my answer `If triangleWcolor is an enum` I don't know it is, I'm just saying IF it is. That said, It is quite likely because: 1) seems to designate a color; 2) he tries to compare with an int; BUT I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a structure to an int without converting it.

if you don't want to convert it then i suggest creating an int in your structure and compare those two ints together.

Comment: `functions are ll located withing a structure "triangleWcolor" in a header file` that's what he wrote after his code  so inside that structure he can place an int to hold any value he want to compare.